# what is SanitizeHelper in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

watching the 'http://guides.rubyonrails.org/' is being studied. "SanitizeHelper" this section does not understand exactly.
Is often used in some cases? 
advice please

Comment: take a look at http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper/sanitize I think that this is what you are looking for

Comment: Oh, that's nice site!thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Rails documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html):

> The SanitizeHelper module provides a set of methods for scrubbing text of undesired HTML elements. These helper methods extend Action View making them callable within your template files.

In other words, you can use this in your views if you only want to allow certain HTML tags in (user submitted) bits of text, but you want to prevent undesired behaviour, such as someone submitting a piece of malicious JavaScript.